# Input/Ouput errors only happening in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, singularity-container

I am using a bioinformatics tool (iMOKA) through singularity. The bash script contains `rm` and `mv` commands as well as `mkdir`. The later works but not the first two. They output the following error:

```
/bin/rm: Input/output error
```

The first to cause problem is line 256 in the script iMOKA_core/scripts/preprocessed.sh, and the few following.

I've read that it could be a hardware error, but I can manually remove these files without any problem; only the script shows the error. I thus suppose that it rules out hardware issues.

What else could it be ?

The server is virtualised if that is helpful. A lot of other tools do not have this problem.

EDIT: after running the script several times on several files (the script is applied to each file, so all the errors mentioned happen for each file), the errors are consistent within batch, but not between batch. Sometimes the `rm` errors disappear for all the files.

EDIT EDIT : it seems the rror might have been due to me binding the folder with input files when running singularity. The singularity image was also in the binded folder. I will see if i can replicate that.

Comment: Depends on what kind of environment your server provides. Maybe you simply don't have permission to *remove* files from the virtual filesystem, even if you have permission to create new files and directories.

Comment: Run with `bash -x`  to at least know what the script is doing

Comment: @chepner I have permissions to remove, and did so after the failed run.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I have access to the code (iMOKA is on github) so I know what it is doing, bu thanks for the `-x` option, never used it before.

Comment: So what's in line 256, what are the options to `rm`, etc.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano `rm -rf ./working_dir` when removing folders, `rm ./file` for files and `mv ./file_location1 ./file_location2` for moving files. None work but the last `rm`. Some use variable names to designate the files, some a string (such as `working_dir`) and others a mix (`{$variable}.txt`).

Comment: Input/Output error is not due to missing files or permission, it might be an underlying filesystem error. How is it mounted?

Comment: Make sure your script is located in the proper directory you expect.  It might be trying to remove something from a restricted filesystem.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano see the EDIT EDIT. When binding the working folder that also happens ton contain the singularity image, the behavior can be weird.